# How to be enable to use man command for mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, manpage

I have recently encountered a problem in using the command man and the switch --help in mysql. Whenever I enter the command "man select" or ....
or when I use the "select --help" I recieve this error message:

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqld --verbose --help' at line 1**

The fact is that neither the "man" command nor the "--help" switch work for any other command. My guess is that the man pages are not installed by my system. I use "ubuntu 14.04" and have installe my LAMP STACK via using the "apt-get install" command.
Would you help me fix this issue? I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: When I enter "man mysqld", nothing happens. In fact the cursor moves down for more to be entered. Although I didn't expect the semicolon to work, I entered it and recieved the error above!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OS command prompt (where you executed the apt-get):

```
$ man mysql
$ mysql --help
```

From within the mysql client:

```
mysql> help select
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must see your manual 
it's prove man command or not.